# VueJs console.log gives me the correct value but it is not updated in the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this function using Vue 2

```
setPrice(id) {
     this.details.forEach((item) => {
           if (item.id === id) {
               item.price = item.priceOne; // item.priceOne = 10
            }
            console.log(item.price) // 10
      });
 },
```

and this input

```
...
<input type="text" v-model="register.price" @keyup.altGraph="setPrice(register.id)" />
```

The idea is that when the user leaves the input empty, they can enter the price again by pressing the "alt gr" key.
(at the moment I do not condition whether the input is empty or not)
The console.log gives me the expected result, but my input does not update that value, but when I click on another part of the page it adds it, which should not be the case because it should update the value at the moment.

I tried using this.$forceUpdate() and this.$set but nothing.

Can you help me, please?

```
setPrice(id) {
     this.details.forEach((item, index) => {
           if (item.id === id) {
              this.$set(item, "price", item.priceOne); // using this.$set
            }
            console.log(this.details[index].price); // 10
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to iterate over the array, just use the `$set` helper to update the array at the index where the item.id === id :

```js
setPrice(id) {
   const index = this.details.findIndex( detail => detail.id === id )
   const foundDetail = this.details[index]
   this.$set(this.details, index,{...foundDetail , price:foundDetail.priceOne })
 }
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks you so much, I had tried other ways that also iterated and I had not thought about it this way